# Is there a way to tell who started an instance in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

We run only a small handful of instances on Google Cloud Platform and we don't run them all the time. Generally we just fire one up, do what we need to do then shut it down... which is great, except when "we" forget to shut them down.

I've been able to track down the relevant [REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) and the [gcloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe) but I don't see anything that says who started the instance. Actually it also doesn't have a timestamp on when it was started.

I did find [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/compute-appengine-timeout-python) python app engine script that I might be able to rewrite to stop the instances after X amount of time, but I'd rather find a way to notify the user who started it and let them know the instance is still running.

Has anyone tried to do something similar or seen a way to get the "starter" of the instance in GCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into the [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/audit-logging) to determine who did what, where, and when. Further, you can use the Stackdriver Logging API method entries.list to [retrieve audit log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#view_api) for your use case.

Also you can choose use the [Activity Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) to know the details such as the authorized user who made the API request.

Comment: Sweet. With those links I was able to construct this gcloud command: `gcloud logging read "resource.type = gce_instance AND jsonPayload.event_subtype = compute.instances.start"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the new API you have to filter on the following:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
resource.labels.instance_id="ID"
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.start"
```